# Determine Probability of a Subset

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Ok - I sometimes play scratch off lottery ticket where you get always get A, E, I, O, and U and then get 13 consonants from the 21 remaining letters of the alphabet. Of course, I usually end up with a seemingly inordinate occurrences of J, X, Q, and Z (Obviously the worst letters in the alphabet for making words, and winning on the ticket!)

By using this formula:

$$C(n,r) = \frac{n!}{r!(n - r)!}$$

I can calculate that there are $203490$ 13-consonant possibilities. But how do I figure out how many of those would include all four of the nasty letters(J,X,Q, and Z)? I guess I would like to know what the probability is for getting 1, 2, 3, or all four of these letters. I am guessing it is much less probable in real life then in these fixed scratch tickets, but I was interested in the comparison!

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that order of letters is unimportant and that letters may not be repeated, you correctly found $\binom{21}{13}=203490$ to be the number of ways to pick thirteen consonants from the alphabet, which in this case refers to the number of possible lottery tickets.

To find the number of these lottery tickets which have exactly $i$ of $J,X,Q,Z$

- Pick which $i$ of $J,X,Q,Z$ are used.  $\binom{4}{i}$ number of ways to do this
- Pick the remaining $13-i$ consonants to be used.  $\binom{17}{13-i}$ number of ways to do this

Applying multiplication principle, there are $\binom{4}{i}\binom{17}{13-i}$ number of different lotto tickets which have exactly $i$ of $J,X,Q,Z$.

Further assuming each possible lottery ticket is equally likely to occur, we may find the probability of an event occuring by dividing the size of the event by the size of sample space.

We have:

$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}\hline
\text{number of J,Q,X,Z}&\text{number of lotto tickets}&\text{probability of occurrence}\\
\hline
0&2380&1.17\%\\
\hline
1&24752&12.16\%\\
\hline
2&74256&36.49\%\\
\hline
3&77792&38.28\%\\
\hline
4&24310&11.95\%\\
\hline
\end{array}$